# Is there a way to create a fade-in/fade-out effect using CSS 3 only?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a way to create a fade-in/fade-out effect on mouse over/out respectively that only uses CSS 3?
If there is, would you say that it is a good way to implement such an effect with CSS only or not?
To me, it seems like a presentation only issue so I'm not sure why JavaScript should be involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hRuR9/2/ ?

It's pretty simple...

```
.box{
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
}

.box:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

As for whether using it or not is a good idea, it depends on your target audience and which browsers you expect them to use or want to support. Recent versions of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox (and I believe Opera) support it. No idea about recent versions of IE, but you can pretty much forget about the older ones.

Comment: I am aware of the compatibility issues but is it a good separation of presentation and behavior?

Comment: Yes I definitely think so, this is all presentation.